# Open a raster file with read and write permissions in rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I am trying to write a function which will help me construct a `rasterio` memory file and return the dataset reader object so I can then play around with it as needed. I am trying to avoid `with` statements because I would like to allow the user to read and write as they deem necessary. This is what I have so far:

```
from rasterio import mask, features, warp
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import rasterio
import numpy as np

def create_memory_file(data, west_bound, north_bound, cellsize, driver='AAIGrid'):
    #data is a numpy array
    dtype = data.dtype
    shape = data.shape
    transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(west_bound, north_bound, cellsize, cellsize)
    memfile = MemoryFile()
    dataset = memfile.open(driver=driver, width= shape[1], height = shape[0], transform=transform, count=1, dtype = dtype)
    dataset.write(data,1)

    return dataset
def close_memory_file(memfile):
    memfile.close()


data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
memfile = create_memory_file(data, 0, 2, 0.5)
memfile.read(1)
```

The last line throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/11202750-002_RA2CE/Basis/common.py", line 214, in <module>
    memfile.read(1)
  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 209, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read
rasterio.errors.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

The memfile apparently only has write permissions because of the following:

```
>>> memfile
<open BufferedDatasetWriter name='/vsimem/3c0572dd-a295-4f2b-a65d-22a404dd5d0f.' mode='w'>
>>> memfile.mode
'w'
```

I have tried various combinations of adding `mode=r+`, `permissions=r+` to my `memfile.open()` call but it won't allow this.

How can I add the read/write mode at the level of the `open` statement?

Comment: What exactly was your error with "mode=r+"?

Comment: calling with `dataset = memfile.open(mode='r+',driver=driver, width= shape[1], height = shape[0], transform=transform, count=1, dtype = dtype)` throws the following type error: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'mode'`

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. The usual way is to write and close, then read. If you want to write again, just overwrite the memfile object.

Comment: Its a memory file... dont you lose it once it is closed?

Comment: Your code throws a different error: `TypeError: an integer is required`. Please make sure your example does showcase the problem you have!

Comment: Not on my computer it doesnt. I get `UnsupportedOperation: not readable`. I'm using `rasterio 1.0.6` with `Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.` Please make sure you are using these versions of the software

Comment: @bugmenot123 That error is only in earlier versions of rasterio . I got it in 1.0a12 but not in 1.0.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `rasterio` <= 1.0.7 this is not possible. You have to write and close, then read. If you want to write again, just overwrite the `memfile` object.

For example:

```
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import rasterio
import numpy as np

def create_memory_file(data, west_bound, north_bound, cellsize, driver='GTIFF'):
    #data is a numpy array
    if data.ndim ==2: # Handle 2 or 3D input arrays
        data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=0)
    dtype = data.dtype
    shape = data.shape
    transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(west_bound, north_bound, cellsize, cellsize)
    with MemoryFile() as memfile:
        with memfile.open(
                driver=driver, width= shape[2], height = shape[1],
                transform=transform, count=shape[0], dtype=dtype) as dataset:
            dataset.write(data)
        return memfile.open()  # <==== Re-open the memfile


data = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]).astype(np.int32)
memfile = create_memory_file(data, 0, 2, 0.5)
print(memfile.read())

data = np.array([[4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11, 12]]).astype(np.int32)
memfile = create_memory_file(data, 0, 2, 0.5)
print(memfile.read())
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]]

[[[ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
```

As of `rasterio` 1.0.8 you can write and read as datasets in a `MemoryFile` are opened in `r+`/`w+` mode. Note that the underlying GDAL driver needs to support [creation of a new dataset from scratch](https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html#footnote1) not just creation of a copy of an existing dataset.

For example:

```
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import rasterio
import numpy as np


def create_memory_file(data, west_bound, north_bound, cellsize, driver='GTIFF'):
    #data is a numpy array
    if data.ndim ==2: # Handle 2 or 3D input arrays
        data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=0)
    dtype = data.dtype
    shape = data.shape
    transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(west_bound, north_bound, cellsize, cellsize)
    with MemoryFile() as memfile:
        dataset = memfile.open(
                driver=driver, width= shape[2], height = shape[1],
                transform=transform, count=shape[0], dtype=dtype)
        dataset.write(data)
        return dataset


data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).astype(np.int32)
memfile = create_memory_file(data, 0, 2, 0.5)
print(memfile.read())

data = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]).astype(np.int32)
memfile.write(data, 1)
print(memfile.read())
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]]

[[[ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
```

Comment: I had gone for a similar solution but I think this one is better. I didn't know you could return stuff from inside with statements in a function. nice going. Do I have to worry about closing the file?

Comment: @user32882 no, it will get garbage collected when it goes out of scope. I just ran a 10,000 iteration loop with a large array and memory usage didn't increase.  Note: I've edited the function in my answer to handle 2 & 3D arrays.

Comment: @user32882 see also edit about `r+` support in rasterio 1.0.8